# Not able to understand Let us C static storage class example

Tags: c

I am not able to understand an example in Let us C by Yashwant Kanetkar. Here is the code snippet:

```
main()
{
    int *j;
    int *fun();
    j = fun();
    // If we add a function call here, the print statement prints a garbage value.
    printf("\n%d",*j);
}

int *fun()
{
    int k = 35;
    return (&k);
}
```

Now in the above code, I am not able to understand why having a function call before the printf statement results in printing a garbage value. I have a vague idea that as the returned value points to a memory location in the stack, something goes wrong when another function is called before printing this value. But I am not able to clearly visualize what happens here. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your code

```
int *fun()
{
    int k = 35;
    return (&k);
}
```

you're returning the address of a local variable from `fun()`. Any usage of the return value leads to [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To explain, once the function `fun()` finishes execution, there is no existence of `k`. So , trying to use something like `&k` is invalid.

<sup>Note: Whatever the explanation is provided in that particular book [related to stack flushing or so], is not standardized in c.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
int k = 35;
```

is local to function `fun()` so once you return from `fun()` the memory allocated for `k` is no more valid and you are returning `&k`(address of that variable) which will lead to undefined behavior